# F#: DataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject method

Tags: json, f#

I am new to programming and F# is my first language.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
let internal saveJsonToFile<'t> (someObject:'t) (filePath: string) =   
    use fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate) 
    (new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<'t>)).WriteObject(fileStream, someObject)

let dummyFighter1 = { id = 1; name = "Dummy1"; location = "Here"; nationality = "Somalia"; heightInMeters = 2.0; weightInKgs = 220.0; weightClass = "Too fat"}
let dummyFighter2 = { id = 2; name = "Dummy2"; location = "There"; nationality = "Afghanistan"; heightInMeters = 1.8; weightInKgs = 80.0; weightClass = "Just Nice"}

let filePath = @"G:\User\Fighters.json"
saveJsonToFile dummyFighter1 filePath
saveJsonToFile dummyFighter2 filePath
```

When I run "saveJsonToFile dummyFighter1 filePath", the information is successfully saved. My problem is this: Once I run "saveJsonToFile dummyFighter2 filePath", it immediately replaces all the contents that are already in the file, i.e., all the information about dummyFighter1.

What changes should I make so that information about dummyFighter2 is appended to the file, instead of replacing information about dummyFighter1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you open a file setting `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` to `FileMode.Append`. Append means "create or append" :

```
use fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append)
```

From MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.filemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

> **FileMode.Append** opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or
>   creates a new file. This requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Append
>   permission. FileMode.Append can be used only in conjunction with
>   FileAccess.Write. Trying to seek to a position before the end of the
>   file throws an IOException exception, and any attempt to read fails
>   and throws a NotSupportedException exception.

Comment: Thanks, Tomasz. I was an idiot for not reading the documentation more carefully :-)

Comment: It's because you try to deserialize a single Fighter and in your file you have a list. try to invoke it like that `readJsonFromFile<Fighter list>` or `readJsonFromFile<List<Fighter>>`

Comment: Thanks, Tomasz, but now I have the following error message... 

"System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The data contract type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[[FSI_0068+Fighter, FSI-ASSEMBLY, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' cannot be deserialized because the required data members 'head, tail' were not found."

Comment: try with that `readJsonFromFile<List<Fighter>>` the you would need to handle the conversion from .NET to fsharp list which is awkward. Why don't you use JsonType provider ? It's much easier to work with json in F# http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html